# What causes this amazon build error in UWP Release mode?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uwp

I'm having issues building for release mode on UWP. We are getting these errors we never had before. We recently migrated from Sql-Net to EFC 1.1.3

We are targeting the fall creators update and setting the minimum to 240.

```
'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'AWSSDK.S3'.

Type 'System.Net.IWebProxy' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig'. There may have been a missing assembly.

'AmazonS3HttpUtil.GetHttpClient(IClientConfig)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'HttpClientHandler.set_Proxy(IWebProxy)'. There may have been a missing assembly.

Method 'AmazonS3HttpUtil.GetHttpClient(IClientConfig)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'HttpClientHandler.set_Proxy(IWebProxy)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
```

EDIT: Nuget packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SDKReference Include="Syncfusion Controls for UWP XAML, Version=15.3.0.33">
        <Name>Syncfusion Controls for UWP XAML</Name>
    </SDKReference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity">
        <Version>3.3.2.15</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core">
        <Version>3.3.18</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3">
        <Version>3.3.11.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights">
        <Version>2.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel">
        <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps">
        <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite">
        <Version>1.1.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
        <Version>5.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp">
        <Version>1.5.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI">
        <Version>1.5.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls">
        <Version>1.5.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
        <Version>10.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Win2D.uwp">
       <Version>1.21.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Can you please specify what NuGet packages are you using in your project?

Comment: @PedroLamas I updated my question. Let me know if there is any other info you need. Thanks much for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Amazon has an issue in their nuspec file for AWS SDK that is causing the NuGet Package Manager to fetch inconsistent dependencies. [Apparently the AWS team is already working on it.](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/776)

Answer (score 1):

We released new versions of the packages today that has a fix for resolving which platform of the SDK to use. Can you give that a try.